# Wifi to usb tethering for usb only laptop

Tags: usb, wifi

For my office windows 10 laptop which doesnt allow any installations and have wifi disabled, i can only access internet via Rj45 or usb tethering through my phone. Is there any usb device available in the market which is usb plug and play do not require any driver / software installation and can convert wifi into usb tethering so i dont have to drag my phone around.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any USB WiFi device I know of would just show up as WiFi on Windows.  The only way to spoof USB tethering would be to install custom drivers on the device.  I would suggest talking to the system administrator about your issue and ask to turn on WiFi.

Comment: @Salocor, I agree that it's easier talking to the system admin and ask to open wifi. Unless you're working for the government or dealing with classified/sensitive data/info, I'm not sure why a system admin would disable wifi. It's not *that* large of a security vulnerability to have wifi enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found a website with a lot of stuff you might need: https://www.pcgamer.com/best-usb-wi-fi-adapter/

(you only need one of those) :)